# BigQuery - How to access a variable in WHERE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new in the world of BigQuery (GoogleSQL) and I try to query value in a table (linked to Firestore).

As I work with firestore, my table has the following structure

```
[{
  "document_name": "pathDocument",
  "document_id": "myDocumentID",
  "timestamp": "2023-04-01 08:23:11.213755 UTC",
  "event_id": "myeventID",
  "operation": "CREATE",
  "data": "{\"Code\":\"0000\",\"Country\":\"China\",\"Currency\":\"CNY\",\"Online\":\"true\",....}",
  "old_data": null
}, ....]
```

My goal is to get the Code inside "data" by doing a filter for different variable includes in "data", for instance Country=China AND Online=true

I already succeed to do it, but I don't know if it's the right way (or optimised) as I do operation in the WHERE :

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Code') as Code,
FROM `****.***_raw_latest` 
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Country') AS STRING) = 'China'
AND
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Online') AS BOOL) = TRUE
LIMIT 50;
```

Remark:

- I use CAST because all data are set as string in "data"
- I may have multiple operation such as >, < ...

Is there a way to do it more properly ?

For instance, I try the following, but the variable Country is not accessible

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Code') as Code,
JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Country') as Country,
FROM `****.***_raw_latest` 
WHERE Country = 'China'
LIMIT 50;
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can use aliases dierectly, you need to repeat the json_extract

Comment: As I said, I'm a beginner, I'll check for what it means !

Comment: Use `JSON_VALUE()` instead of `JSON_EXTRACT()` and removing `CAST`ing will make your query more concise.

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#legacy_json_extraction_functions) returns *JSON-formatted string* which is different from a *BigQuery string*. So you can't simply compare both like in your query.

```sql
CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Country') AS STRING) = 'China'
```

> above expression is always false since **JSON_EXTRACT** returns `"China"`, not `China`.

Whereas [`JSON_VALUE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#standard_json_extraction_functions_recommended) extracts a BigQuery string directly from a json string and returns `China`, not `"China"`.

---

You can consider below for this

> My goal is to get the Code inside "data" by doing a filter for different variable includes in "data", for instance Country=China AND Online=true

```sql
WITH `foo.bar_raw_latest` AS (
  SELECT "{\"Code\":\"0000\",\"Country\":\"China\",\"Online\":\"true\"}" data
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Code') code
  FROM `foo.bar_raw_latest`
 WHERE JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Country') = 'China'
   AND JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Online') = 'true';

-- Query results
+------+
| code |
+------+
| 0000 |
+------+
```

Comment: If I need to filter with another filter by doing a comparison (let's say I have a key 'Price' inside my data. So the following '`WHERE JSON_VALUE(data, '$.Price') >10` could not work, should I use `CAST( ) ` ? Or is there a way to do that without extra operation ?

Comment: JSON_VALUE returns a value as a string, so you need to cast it to another data type using `CAST` for numeric comparison.